# What could be causing my second React JSX function to fail to return <li> elements, despite properly filtered data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am creating a simple search bar element in React JSX. I'm trying to render a list of elements that include whatever is in a search query. I basically take an array of all the elements and then I use .filter() function to find everything that includes the query. After that I use .map() function to loop through the results and render

elements for each object. I needed to create two different functions for two different datasets as one is an array deeper.

```
<ul>


{                    
 this.state.searchQuery &&
                                
     this.props.searchDB.projects.filter((project)=> {
         if (this.state.searchQuery === '' || this.state.searchQuery === null) {
            return project;
         } else if (project.projectName.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase())) {
            return project;
         } else {
            return null
         }
     }).map((project, index) => {
         //THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED
         return(
             <li key={'project_' + index}>
                 {index + '_' + project.projectName}
             </li>
         )
    })
                                
}

{
     this.state.searchQuery &&
                                
         this.props.searchDB.mentions.forEach((mentionYear) => {
    
               mentionYear.filter((mention) => {
    
                   if (this.state.searchQuery === '' || this.state.searchQuery === null) {
                     return mention
                   } else if (mention.mentionTitle.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase())) {
                     return mention
                   } else {
                     return null
                   }
              }).map((mention, mentionIndex) => {
                   console.log(mention.mentionTitle)
                   //THIS LOGS DATA AS IT SHOULD BUT DOESN'T RENDER ELEMENTS
                                                
                   return(
                            <li key={'project_' + mentionIndex}>
                               {mentionIndex + '_' + mention.mentionTitle}
                            </li>
                         )
                   })
               }
             ) 
}

</ul>
```

The first function works fine and returns a

element as it should. For some reason the second one does not and it doesn't return any element at all, even though it is basically the same code. Strange is that the data is there, I can log it from the map function and I can see that it is filtered properly. Can someone explain to me what's wrong? I tried quite a lot of possibile mistakes I could have made but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second version never *does anything* with the result of `.map()`.  It's invoked inside a `forEach()` callback, but its result is discarded.  Contrast that to the first version where the result of `.map()` is part of the JSX and rendered.

Don't use `forEach()` for this.  If the intent is that the `.forEach()` iteration should produce a result just like in the first version, then what you want isn't `forEach()`.  What you want is `.map()`.

For example:

```
{
  this.state.searchQuery &&
    this.props.searchDB.mentions.map((mentionYear) => {
      return mentionYear.filter((mention) => {
        // etc.
      }).map((mention, mentionIndex) => {
        // etc.
      });
    })
}
```

Basically, repeat the same pattern/structure you already know works when iterating over a collection in JSX to produce a rendered result.

Comment: You are right, this fixes my problem:) I also see what mistake I did so thank you!